# Secure LDAP object manipulation with VBscript using alternate credentials

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap

I'm aware of using ADsDSOobject with explicit credentials to connect to an AD object to read attributes, list members, etc.  And the GetObject("LDAP//...") method for manipulating those objects (adding group members, changing properties, etc.), but is there a way to manipulate attributes and memberships with explicit credentials?

The first method I'm referring to is something like...

```
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
conn.Provider = "ADsDSOobject"
conn.Properties("User ID") = AD_Username
conn.Properties("Password") = AD_Password
conn.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True
conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
```

But none of the script examples that perform tasks like adding a user to a domain group can use this approach as far as I know.  Is there a way to do that somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VBScript, very often, you are using ADSI to add user to group.  Here is a sample code to add a user to a domain group

```
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://CN=jeffsmith,DC=fabrikam,DC=com")
Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://CN=group1,DC=fabrikam,DC=com")
objGroup.add(objUser.ADsPath)
```

It works fine but it's always using your current user credentails.  It's because `GetObject` doesn't allow you to specify alternate credentials.

To specify another credentails, you need to replace `GetObject` by [OpenDSObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
Const ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION = 1
Set openDS = GetObject("LDAP:") 

Set objUser = openDS.OpenDSObject("LDAP://CN=jeffsmith,DC=fabrikam,DC=com",
    "username", 
    "password",
    ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION)

Set objGroup = openDS.OpenDSObject("LDAP://CN=group1,DC=fabrikam,DC=com",
    "username", 
    "password",
    ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION)

objGroup.add(objUser.ADsPath)
```

Comment: Thanks Harvey!  I don't know why I didn't see that before.

Comment: @Harvey Hello Harvey , I'm facing similar problem . I want to fetch user details from active directory using alternate credentials . Can you give me any sample code of it . Any example , any clue will be fine . I posted my question in stackoverflow . can you look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56183055/adodb-connection-error-80040e21-read-only-property-value-was-not-set?noredirect=1#comment99000943_56183055