# Adding printer via VBS script

Tags: networking, printing, vbscript, installation

I hope someone can help me with following issue:
I'm trying automatically install network printer: first script asks user for his network credentials and then run second one, installing a printer. Problem is: scripts not throws any errors but no printer added:

```
Dim objNetwork
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strUserName = InputBox("What is your username? (domain\username)")
objShell.Run "runas /user:" & strUserName & " ""wscript.exe C:\pbg.vbs"" "
```

pbg.vbs:

```
Dim objNetwork
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\10.100.1.29\Canon"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\10.100.1.29\Canon"
```

I made such two-file design because first part is run during boot time and user key-in his username/pass (there can be different users at this shared workstation) and then script use username/pass to call second part of script which is installing network printer

Thank You in advance

Comment: [This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490974.aspx) or [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725868.aspx) can simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the connection in your VBScript to the print server by authenticating right inside the connect string with the user ID/Password.

Place the code you have in front of the code you have for PBG.vbs and do t all within the code itself (faster/cleaner). You could make PBG.vbs a function within new code too.

Here are some links with the different ways:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
 [Secure LDAP object manipulation with VBscript using alternate credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285247/secure-ldap-object-manipulation-with-vbscript-using-alternate-credentials/5308028#5308028)
 [How to make an Active Directory query from VBScript on a non-domain computer using domain credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655718/how-to-make-an-active-directory-query-from-vbscript-on-a-non-domain-computer-usi)

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I probably should clarify why it's splitted into 2 files - that's because it should support different users - so script is autorun on machine reboot and then user input his/her username/pass and script use it to run second script. Users can change because it's for shared workstation. Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same thing basically with Active Directory groups that install printers for users in various parts of the building.  Just add them to the group and the associated script fires and installs the printer local to that area of the building.

Since you're also working with a domain environment you don't need the first script.  When the user logs on the second script would execute using rights obtained from credentials used during windows log on and the printer would install for them.