# How to provide hostname and credentials to "LDAP://"?

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I need to have an Active Directory Shadow Groups (aka Active Directory Dynamic Group), based on several DN's.

I've searched high and low for a simple tool that would allow me to do this, and finally found Dan Holme's excellent script (quoted below) at http://kb.caresys.com.cn/4052785/need-script-add-all-accounts-active-directory-security-group (and a few other places)
I also found several PowerShell scripts, but they all appear to have much harder dependencies and I need a tool that's as stand-alone as possible. They also all have the same problem as I'm faced with here.

The Group_Shadow.vbs script performs exactly what I need with one exception:
**I need to be able to specify the AD's Host, port number and credentials (login and password).**

The script assumes that `"LDAP://"` is pointing to the correct AD, and I guess the AD Credentials are derived from the user running the script?

I did find a hint about how to set the host name and password, by changing the `"LDAP://"` string into `"LDAP://LDAP_HOST:LDAP_PORT/"`.
That seems pretty easy to implement - but there were a few comments stating it didn't work...

I also found a hint about setting the credentials:

```
Dim LDAP ' As IADsOpenDSObject 
Set LDAP = GetObject("LDAP:") 
Set obj = LDAP.OpenDSObject("LDAP://", "domain\name", "password", ADS_USE_ENCRYPTION OR ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION)
```

This appear to be the hard part (being totally novice in both the VBScript and Active Directory world), and I simply can't figure out how to combine to two.

I hope the community can help me out, either by assisting fixing this script or by pointing to a different solution.

Thanks in advance!

The Script:

```
'==========================================================================
'
' VBScript Source File -- Created with SAPIEN Technologies PrimalScript 2007
'
' NAME: Group_Shadow.vbs
'
' AUTHOR: Dan Holme , Intelliem
' DATE  : 12/12/2007
'
' USAGE:  
' cscript.exe Group_Shadow.vbs
'
' Dynamically updates the membership of a group
' to match the objects returned from an Active Directory query
'
' See the Windows Administration Resource Kit for documentation
'
' Neither Microsoft nor Intelliem guarantee the performance
' of scripts, scripting examples or tools.
'
' See www.intelliem.com/resourcekit for updates to this script
'
' (c) 2007 Intelliem, Inc
'==========================================================================
Option Explicit

Dim sDomainDN
Dim sGroupSAMAccountName
Dim aSearchOUs
Dim sQuery

'==========================================================================
' CONFIGURATION BLOCK
' Domain's DN
sDomainDN = "dc=domain,dc=local"
' sAMAccountName of shadow group
sGroupSAMAccountName = "Security Group"
' An array of one or more OUs to search
aSearchOUs = Array("ou=Something,dc=domain,dc=local")
' LDAP query that will be run in each OU
sQuery = " (&(objectCategory=computer)(name=GA*));distinguishedName;subtree"
'==========================================================================

' Create dictionaries
Dim dResults
Set dResults = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dResults.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' Case INsensitive
Dim dTargetMembership
Set dTargetMembership = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dTargetMembership.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' Case INsensitive
Dim dCurrentMembership
Set dCurrentMembership = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dCurrentMembership.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' Case INsensitive
Dim dMembershipChanges
Set dMembershipChanges = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dMembershipChanges.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' Case INsensitive

' Perform LDAP searches, adding to final list stored in dTargetMembership
Dim sSearchOU
Dim sLDAPQuery
For Each sSearchOU In aSearchOUs
    sLDAPQuery = "<LDAP://" & sSearchOU & ">;" & sQuery
    Set dResults = AD_Search_Dictionary(sLDAPQuery)
    Call DictionaryAppend(dResults, dTargetMembership)
Next

' Locate group
Dim sGroupADsPath
Dim oGroup
sGroupADsPath = ADObject_Find_Generic(sGroupSAMAccountName, sDomainDN)
If sGroupADsPath = "" Then
    ' Error handling: group not found
    WScript.Quit
End If
Set oGroup = GetObject(sGroupADsPath)

' Get members and store in dictionary
Dim aMembers
aMembers = oGroup.GetEx("member")
Set dCurrentMembership = ArrayToDictionary(aMembers)

' Calculate the "delta" between the current and desired state
Set dMembershipChanges = Dictionary_Transform(dCurrentMembership, dTargetMembership)

' Make the membership changes based on the transform dictionary's instructions
Dim sMember
For Each sMember In dMembershipChanges
    If UCase(dMembershipChanges.Item(sMember)) = "ADD" Then
        oGroup.Add "LDAP://" & sMember
    End If
    If UCase(dMembershipChanges.Item(sMember)) = "DELETE" Then
        oGroup.Remove "LDAP://" & sMember
    End If
Next

WScript.Quit

' ======================
' FUNCTIONS FROM LIBRARY
' ======================

' #region Dictionary routines

Function ArrayToDictionary(ByRef aArray)
    ' Converts a one-dimensional array into a dictionary.
    ' Assumes elements in array are unique
    Dim dDic
    Dim aElement
    Set dDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dDic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' Case INsensitive

    On Error Resume Next ' trap duplicate array elements
    For Each aElement In aArray
        dDic.Add aElement, 0        
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set ArrayToDictionary = dDic
End Function

Sub DictionaryAppend(ByRef dNewElements, ByRef dDictionary)
    ' Appends the elements of dNewElements to dDictionary
    Dim sKey

    On Error Resume Next ' trap duplicate array elements
    For Each sKey In dNewElements.keys
        dDictionary.Add sKey, dNewElements.Item(sKey)
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Function Dictionary_Transform(ByVal dOriginal, ByVal dFinal)
    ' Retunrs a dictionary with a list of update operations required
    ' so that dOriginal is transformed to dFinal

    Dim dTransform, sKey
    Set dTransform = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dTransform.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' Case INsensitive

    For Each sKey In dFinal.Keys
        If Not dOriginal.Exists(sKey) Then
            dTransform.Add sKey, "ADD"
        End If
    Next

    For Each sKey In dOriginal.Keys
        If Not dFinal.Exists(sKey) Then
            dTransform.Add sKey, "DELETE"
        End If
    Next

    Set Dictionary_Transform = dTransform

End Function

' #endregion

' #region Active Directory object find routines

Function ADObject_Find_Generic(ByVal sObject, ByVal sSearchDN)
    ' Version 071130
    ' Takes any input (name, DN, or ADsPath) of a user, computer, or group, and
    ' returns the ADsPath of the object as a way of validating that the object exists
    '
    ' INPUTS:   sObject                 DN or ADsPath to an object
    '                                   sAMAccountName (pre-Windows 2000 logon name) of a user or group
    '                                   computer name of a computer
    '           sSearchDN               the DN within which to search (often, the DN of the domain, e.g. dc=contoso, dc=com)
    '
    ' RETURNS:  ADObject_Find_Generic   ADsPath (LDAP://...) of the object
    '                                   blank if object was not found
    '
    ' NOTES:    ASSUMPTION: computers, users & groups have unique names. See note inline.
    '
    ' REQUIRES  AD_Search_Array routine
    '           AD_Search_RS routine
    '           ADObject_Validate routine

    Dim aResults, sLDAPQuery
    Select Case ADObject_NameType(sObject)
        Case ""
            ADObject_Find_Generic = ""
        Case "adspath"
            ADObject_Find_Generic = ADObject_Validate(sObject)
        Case "distinguishedname"
            ADObject_Find_Generic = ADObject_Validate("LDAP://" & sObject)
        Case "name"
                ' Assumption: No computer has the same name as a user's or group's sAMAccountName
                ' otherwise, this query will return more than one result
                sLDAPQuery = "<LDAP://" & sSearchDN & ">;" & _
                             "(|(samAccountName=" & sObject & ")(samAccountName=" & sObject & "$));" & _
                             "aDSPath;subtree"
                aResults = AD_Search_Array (sLDAPQuery)
                If Ubound(aResults) = -1 Then
                    ADObject_Find_Generic = ""
                Else
                    ADObject_Find_Generic = aResults(0)
                End If
    End Select

End Function

Function ADObject_NameType(ByVal sObjectName)
    ' Version 071204
    ' Evaluates sObjectName to determine what type of name it is
    ' Returns   ADObject_NameType   adspath
    '                               distinguishedname
    '                               name
    '                               blank if sObjectName = ""

    Dim sNameType

    If Len(sObjectName) = 0 Then
        sNameType = ""

    ElseIf Len(sObjectName) < 3 Then
        ' can't be a DN or an ADsPath - must be a name
        sNameType = "name"

    ElseIf Ucase(Left(sObjectName,3)) = "CN=" Then
        ' is a DN
        sNameType = "distinguishedname"

    ElseIf Len(sObjectName) < 8 Then
        ' too short to be an ADsPath and isn't a DN, so it must be a name
        sNameType = "name"

    ElseIf UCase(Left(sObjectName, 7)) = "LDAP://" Then
        ' is already an ADsPath
        sNameType = "adspath"

    Else
        ' must be a name
        sNameType = "name"

    End If

    ADObject_NameType = sNameType
End Function

Function ADObject_Validate(ByVal sObjectADsPath)
    ' Version 071122
    ' Returns ADsPath of object as a way of validating that the object exists
    '
    ' INPUTS:   sObjectADsPath      ADsPath of object to test
    ' RETURNS:  ADObject_Validate   Path of object (if it exists) or blank

    Dim oObject
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oObject = GetObject(sObjectADsPath)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ADObject_Validate = ""
        Err
```

Comment: The hostname goes after the `//`, just as in any other URL. Can't help you about the credentials.

Comment: @EJP Thanks. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there are two answers to take note of in regard to "LDAP://" credentials.

**First**, specifically to the script I posted, I simply had to open my eyes!
Almost the last line of the script there were already options to add the credentials:

```
oConnection.Open "", vbNullString, vbNullString
```

Simply had to be correctly populated:

```
oConnection.Open "", "username", "password"
```

**Second**, a more general description was already provided by @Harvey Kwok in this SO answer: [Secure LDAP object manipulation with VBscript using alternate credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285247/secure-ldap-object-manipulation-with-vbscript-using-alternate-credentials)